# Creating a Null relational date type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I am converting a MySQL application that contains relationals of the form:

```
mydate < '2000-01-01'::date
```

MySQL will return true in this instance if `mydate` is `Null` and PostgreSQL will not. There are thousands of lines like this, too many and too varied to modify. I am investigating using a custom type to emulate this behavior, and I would like to utilize  built-in I/O functions for Date as a base instead of rolling my own. Am I on the right track, and where do I find the documentation for them?

Comment: "*MySQL will return true in this instance if mydate is Null*" - really? I didn't know MySQL was _that_ broken (and it doesn't seem like it does actually: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53dcb/1) But you should rather fix your application to handle nulls properly. Or update all `NULL` values for `mydate` to `-infinity`

Comment: I can assure you that it does.  I agree in principal, but modifying 10k lines by hand seemed less than ideal.

Comment: Then change all `NULL` dates to `-infinity` and you don't need to touch the SQL code.

Comment: That would break programs in the system that use a null date to determine if a record has been modified. There may be thousands of statements involved.